# AOL bounces with: AOL will not accept delivery of this message

Tags: sendmail, spam

AOL started bouncing emails from my mail server with the following error:

```
521 5.2.1 :  AOL will not accept delivery of this message.
554 5.5.0 Remote protocol error
```

On the troubleshooting page AOL asks for specific error code but all I get is a generic message. The emails are sent from Outlook, without any attachments. I don't send out any mass email/newsletters, only personal email.

What can cause this and how should I proceed? Without the specific code I can't proceed with AOL. Have anyone had this problem?

Comment: Your mail server correctly set up (mailname, reverse ip in dns, stuff like that)? A tcpdump on your mail server, to see the actual smtp dialog?

Comment: Currently this doesn't really constitute a question. Please follow [these guidelines](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) to reword your question to something that people may be able to help you with.

Comment: @BE77Y thanks for the hint, I added some questions.

Comment: @Dan I tried but the communication is encrypted. I don't want to play around with encryption in the middle of a workday. I guess sendmail will provide the important info in the logs anyways...

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907191/aol-rejecting-email-sent-via-php-mail-error-5-2-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try submitting the form with no error code selected, and hope for the best. If you're lucky, a human being might read it.

You can also try contacting AOL Postmaster by phone, on +1 703 265-4670 ([reportedly](https://intoolate.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/aol-customer-service-phone-numbers-and-contact-info-updated-3-03-2010/) AOL postmaster operations are now being handled in India; you've been warned).

Answer (score 8):

Checking around for similar errors, and looking through [AOL's Postmaster errors](http://postmaster.aol.com/Postmaster.Errors.php), nothing immediately ties up with what you've reported but doing some cross-referencing (for example from [this thread](http://forums.networksolutions.com/nsmail-f47-ndr-non-delivery-reports-for-server-ips-being-blocked-t10332-st525.html)), the linked error codes (`521 5.2.1` which you reference in your question) are possibly linked to the `421 CON:B1` error code from the above-linked error code list from AOL, which reads:

> 21 CON:B1 The IP address has been tempfailed due to a spike in
>   unfavorable e-mail statistics.

It strikes me as odd that they would have ambiguous error code reporting, but since we currently do not have very much else to go on, I suggest that you check your IP reputation using the [AOL tool](http://postmaster.aol.com/Reputation.php) and follow up accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately AOL tool reports my IP reputation as _Undisclosed_ and grepping my logs for AOL (aim.com etc) I see only a handful of messages from users who reported the problem.

Comment: @moorray Same boat too. All the sudden it's wonked out, IP rep as *Undisclosed*. This happened last year too, I'm assuming it's the ambiguous error reporting BE77Y mentions above. You can try using one of these forms https://postmaster.aol.com/trouble-ticket

Comment: If they are in process of updating your 'reputation' to 'poor' OR they are in process of whitelisting your IP, you will get undisclosed. I can't guarantee this as I do not work there, but have had experience w/ OP problem/question.. and the aol 'postmaster' group in general.